# HTTPS Tomcat Reroute Requests

Tags: java, tomcat, https, okhttp

I have an application currently running on a Tomcat webserver. My application makes https requests to a websites api which has an IP rate limit.

I would like to get around this by re-routing my https traffic to a proxy server but i'm having some difficulty.

Is Tomcat able to do this by setting the -Dhttps.proxyHost and -Dhttps.proxyPort or is this something that will need to be implemented in the code?

I'm currently using okhttp3 and retrofit to make the api requests. The Proxy i'm using can also be trusted to reroute the requests.

Any help / guidance will be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you are mixing things a bit.

Comment: Your Tomcat has nothing to do with proxying the requests since you are using http client for the requests. Tomcat is only the container in which your application is running. To bypass the limit you would need to access that server from different IP addresses. Do you have more than one IP address to use?

Comment: I thought I might be! I have purchased ten private proxy servers which support https. I'd like to use these as the middle man between my client and the https server if possible.

Comment: I'd like to run ten instances of the application on one server, each which use one of the proxy servers to communicate with the https api.

Comment: Not sure if it's appropriate to ask SO how to circumvent a security/licensing restriction a vendor has in place...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply...

Your application should do the proxying, one way could be in a round robin, i.e. for each request to api server get the next proxy from the list of proxy address and port. than something like:

```
public static final MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
  Proxy proxyTest = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,new InetSocketAddress("proxy", proxyPort));

  OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient()
  .proxy(proxyTest)
  .build();

  String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {

    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .post(body)
        .build();
    try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
      return response.body().string();
    }
  }
```

HTH,
Gal